# Makefile not generating debugging information with -g flag

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, makefile

I recently moved from working in the terminal to VScode and am needing to generate debugging information to use with the debugger in vscode.

My makefile is:

```
SRCS =  src/ft_argcheck.c       \
        src/ft_operations.c     \
        src/ft_stcutils.c       \
        src/push_swap.c

NAME    = push_swap
INCS    = inc/push_swap.h
OBJS    = $(SRCS:c=o)
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror
RM      = rm -f
LIBFT = libft/libft.a
LIBFT_DIR = libft

.PHONY: all bonus clean fclean re

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    @make -C $(LIBFT_DIR) --silent
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) -L $(LIBFT_DIR) -lft

clean:
    @$(RM) $(OBJS)
    @make -s clean -C $(LIBFT_DIR)

fclean: clean
    @$(RM) $(NAME)
    @make -s fclean -C $(LIBFT_DIR)

re: fclean all
```

But despite adding the -g flag, no debugging information is generated. on which I can run lldb.

Comment: Your Makefile seems not to contain any rule for building the object files from the source files. I'm not sure how object files are built in this case but I assume that `$(CFLAGS)` is ignored in this case.

Comment: Remove all the `@` prefixing the commands to get them printed after variable expansions. Should find `-g` in there.

Comment: If you don't have a rule for building object files, then this makefile will use the built-in rule which should use `CFLAGS`, and I can't explain the behavior you're seeing.  If you do have a rule for building object files that you forgot to show us, then that might explain it.  Please cut and paste (with formatting) the compile lines that are invoked by make to build your object files: do they contain `-g`?  Why do you think "no debugging information is generated"?  What happens to make you believe that?

Comment: If you modified the `CFLAGS` variable in your makefile after having already built the project then that will not cause the existing `.o` files to be out of date with respect to the corresponding `.c` files.  Regardless, then, of whether the executable itself is out of date, that won't get you debug symbols if you didn't have them already.  If that's your issue then `make fclean; make all` should resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers (Removing @ didn't really give me much more information, as it did show the -g flag and I already tried remaking everything with fclean). I seem to have figured out an easy fix with the help of a friend:

add a rule "debug"

```
debug: 
    $(CC) -g $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCS) $(LIBFT) $(SRCS) -o $(NAME)
```

which we can run just when we want to generate the debugging information and run this directly with $(SRCS) instead of running it on the $(OBJS) as in the normal command.

Answer (score 1):

A good proposal is to remove the `@`s in front of the command names to see what commands `make` is executing.... To make a program debuggable, you need to check that all the compilation steps are done using the `-g` flag and that the linking step has also included the `-g` flag.  Also a good option is to specify no optimization so you will not get to problems with breakpoints you cannot fix because the compiler has eliminated or changed the final code, and has broken the correspondence between source lines and points in the code.

If you take off all the `@`s there, you will see the commands as `make` is executing them, think you don't see now.  I think there's a command (berkeley make has it) to make `make` to print the commands even though the `@`s remain in place.

By the way, as you are telling you are using `vscode` it should be fine if you execute `make` on the command line alone, to see the output of the commands, and try to see if it is some problem with make or with vscode itself.

As you have not provided your complete project, I'm sorry to say that I can only test it with dumb/fake files and no program can be made to test it with gdb.

I guess that the problem is that you have put your project sources in a different directory than where the program is built, and the sources cannot be found by gdb and so, no source debugging can be done because gdb cannot find the source files.  Gdb has some way to specify the path to the source files... You should look at gdb documentation.